# Are there any guiding principles for using the Gutter space in web products (websites, mobile sites, mobile apps)?

Tags: website-design, mobile-application, mobile-web, guidelines, white-space

What % of page can be taken up by the gutter space?
Can the gutter space vary when the website/mobile-site are seen in different resolutions?
Is it okay to have gutter space in an App?

Comment: An important point is to prevent the [Hermann grid illusion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53791/avoiding-the-hermann-grid-illusion)

Answer (score 2):

Gutter space are a part of **white space**. It can be seen as a tool for designers to bring clarity, guide the users and [has other benefits](http://uxmyths.com/post/2059998441/myth-28-white-space-is-wasted-space). It is a relevant solution for **any device you are designing for**.

> What % of page can be taken up by the gutter space?

[Material design](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing) recommends 16dp.

[image]